# RibbonActions.js Deprecated in Dynamics 365 Unified Interface. Is there any new JS Library replacing RibbonActions.js?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am using the OOTB **Send Direct Email** button to send bulk emails. This works fine in Classic mode but throws below error in the **Unified Interface**.

After some research I found out that ***/_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js*** is deprecated and ***$webresource*** must be used instead.

Is there any way I can find the new library for `RibbonActions.js`?

Looked into D365 Documentation and Ribbon Workbench Documentation, found nothing.

Any solutions would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `$webresource:RibbonActions.js` & press the enter button/lens icon, it will prompt you to choose one, then click on `$webresource:Sales/_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js`. This should work.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ArunVinoth, Tried this as well. It takes the new path but still the same error is coming saying it is not supported. I read in a blog, which says that RibbonActions.js is deprecated and Main_system_library.js is used but could not find the function in that. Any idea?

Comment: @RonakLodaya then probably you need to create a ticket with MS support team to ask the PG team for replacement documented (supported) functionality for this..

Comment: Hi @ArunVinoth, We have raised the ticket, waiting for the solution.

Comment: Aren't these libraries getting deprecated? @ArunVinoth