# CommandBarActions.js Deprecated in Dynamics 365 Unified Interface. Is there any new JS Library replacing CommandBarActions.js?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

There was a similar question here regarding **RibbonActions.js**, but I could not find the library that contains `Mscrm.CommandBarActions.launchOnDemandWorkflowForm` (it used to be in `/_static/_common/scripts/commandbaractions.js`). I need to start WF without using code.

**Does anyone know where this function is stored right now?**

*P.S. I know about smart buttons.*

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055998/ribbonactions-js-deprecated-in-dynamics-365-unified-interface-is-there-any-new

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your requirement of launching without code, but this is how you can call a workflow form the Ribbon using RibbonWorkbench. https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365enterprisecloudfronts/posts/call-workflow-directly-from-a-button-using-ribbon-workbench

If you *can* run js to initiate the workflow, you can execute it passing parameters with the Xrm.WebApi.online.execute method seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/online/execute

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Smart Buttons in the Ribbon Workbench to run Workflow, WebHook, Report, Quick JS in model-driven apps (Dynamics 365 UCI).
 http://develop1.net/public/post/2019/12/21/smart-buttons-for-the-unified-interface